# QtCreator and Command Line Arguments

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is there a way to send command line arguments to a program being debugged in QtCreator?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Go in the "Project" part on the left of QtCreator and then in the "Run Settings" tab. There is a Arguments line edit where you can put all you need to pass to your app when launching it.

**For Qt Creator from Qt 5.6**
Go in the "Projects part on the left and then in the "Build & Run" tab. Here you have a "Command line arguments" edit where you can put all parameters you want to pass to your app.

Comment: if you have a ';' in one of your params, put a '\' before it. eg. `--docroot=static-content;/resources --deploy-path=/` becomes `--docroot=static-content\;/resources --deploy-path=/` in qtcreator run settings page .. otherwise it'll stop reading at ';' and ignore all the rest of the command line.

Comment: This does not match QtCreator version 3.3.2 There is no "Run Settings" or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep. There's two buttons in a dark-grey box, one called **Build** and one called **Run**. You need to click the **Run** button and it will switch to it for you.

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer.  Deprecate the green checkmark and note the fact.

Comment: Instead of downvoting a correct answer when question was asked (7 years ago), why not only update the answer by replacing "Run settings" by "Build and Run"?

Answer (score 33):

As the accepted answer is outdated, I post this picture which answers the question for a newer version of QtCreator:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

For Qt Creator 3.3.2, to set the working directory and command line arguments:

Projects (far left of Qt Creator)
- Build & Run (tab)
-- Run (sub tab) - brings up "Run Settings"
--- Arguments: ...
--- Working directory: ...

Answer (score 3):

As per the image below, **Build & Run** has an input for command line arguments (in the screen shot it is highlighted with a blue border as it has the focus) :-

[image]

Qt Creator with Qt version 5.6.1