# Pass arguments to main function at compiling time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt-creator

I am a novice programmer learning C++ and the following question can be considered cross platform as I tried this both in Visual Studio 2010/12 and Qt Creator in Linux Mint.

I have set up the main() function of my program to accept command line arguments like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if(argc < 5)
    {
        printf("Not enough input parameters!\n");
        printf("Usage:\n");
        printf("'program' lamda1 lamda2 Attraction_Range Order_Param_Range\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        lamda1 = atof(argv[1]);
        lamda2 = atof(argv[2]);
        attRange = atof(argv[3]);
        oRange = atof(argv[4]);
        cout << lamda1 << lamda2 << attRange << oRange << endl;
    }
}
```

However, when I hit `Ctrl+F5` in Visual Studio or `Ctrl+R` in Qt Creator, to compile, the code forks to the `if` statement because I cannot input any parameters. Can I somehow pass initial arguments to my program, so that when it compiles, it can immediately go to the `else` part of the above example?

I am sorry if this is a duplicate/ wrong question, but I didn't even know how to search for this on the net.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You might as well not pass them at all, if you're going to do it at compile time.

Comment: Qt is a framework. Qt Creator is an IDE. Neither of those is a compiler. Your question is not cross-platform at all. You're asking the same a question for two different IDEs. That's not a good idea.

Comment: @mwerschy: Yes, that is true. I just thought it would save some time, since now I have to navigate to the generated executable and type the command in `powershell/ bash`. @Mat: You are correct of course. The terminology still eludes me...

Comment: Then you still want run-time, you just want the IDE to do it for you. @Riateche has the correct answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio: [How could I run a project with some parameters in Visual Studio?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsstart/thread/f1157782-772f-4db3-bed7-d3cd99300d11/)

In Qt Creator: [QtCreator and Command Line Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593288/qtcreator-and-command-line-arguments)